# Pandas time-series groupby with custom function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I have a timeseries with several products. For each product I want to remove null extremes, and in the middle I want to substitute double 0 to np.nan. Here is an example:

```
Date Id  Units Should be
1    a   0     remove row
2    a   5     5
3    a   0     np.nan
4    a   0     np.nan
5    a   1     1
6    a   3     3

1    b   4     4
2    b   2     2
3    b   0     0
4    b   4     4
5    b   0     remove row
6    b   0     remove row
```

I tried using groupby and for to getting indexes, but I wasnt able to combine the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
## PART 1: remove the external 0s
# get rows with 0
m = df['Units'].ne(0)
# get masks to identify the middle values
m1 = m.groupby(df['Id']).cummax()
m2 = m[::-1].groupby(df['Id']).cummax()

# slice the "internal" rows
out = df[m1&m2]

## PART2: replace stretches of 2 0s
g = m.ne(m.groupby(df['Id']).shift()).cumsum()
m3 = df.groupby(['Id', g]).transform('size').eq(2)

out.loc[m2&~m, 'Units'] = pd.NA
```

output:

```
   Date Id  Units Should be
1     2  a    5.0         5
2     3  a    NaN    np.nan
3     4  a    NaN    np.nan
4     5  a    1.0         1
5     6  a    3.0         3
6     1  b    4.0         4
7     2  b    2.0         2
8     3  b    NaN         0
9     4  b    4.0         4
```